# Azure AD B2C first sign in with temporary password strange behaviour

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have Azure AD B2C sign-in policy for local accounts. 
When we are creating new users via Graph API with temporary password and flag `ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = true;` and such users try to login first time in the browser where previously was issued any other session at https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENNANT_NAME/oauth2/authorize url - we have next strange behaviour :

1. User fills out email and temporary password, submit the form.
2. Microsoft prompt to change the password with the message -  "Update your password
   You need to update your password because this is the first time you are signing in, or because your password has expired."
3. User enters current temporary password, new password, confirm new password and submits the form
4. Sometimes chrome shows empty page with message "Bad Request", other times user redirects back to sign in page with message - "By security reasons sign in again"
5. User enters again email and temporary password, submits the form
6. Microsoft again force user to change the password with the same message as at step #2 , but now if user enters temporary password in "Current password" field - Microsoft will not accept it and show an error that password incorrect. Instead of, user should enter password which he provided as new at step #3 and change it to a completely new one.
7. Sometimes user gets redirected to return url with access token, sometimess steps 4-6 repeated again.

If check the audit log from Azure AD it will look like :

[image]

This is not reproducing in newly opened incognito page

Comment: With which type of policy is this occurring?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett , Sign In policy for local accounts